# Tensorflow training: why two successive training is better than one training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regression

I'm working on a regression problem using Keras+Tensorflow. And I've found something interesting. 
1) here are the two models, which are actually the same except that the first model is using a globally defined 'optimizer'.

```
optimizer = Adam() #as a global variable
def OneHiddenLayer_Model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(300 * inputDim, input_dim=inputDim, kernel_initializer='normal', activation=activationFunc)) 
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

def OneHiddenLayer_Model2():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(300 * inputDim, input_dim=inputDim, kernel_initializer='normal', activation=activationFunc)) 
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam())
    return model
```

2) Then, I use two schemes to train the datasets (training set(scaleX, Y); testing set(scaleTestX, testY)).

2.1) Scheme1. two successive fitting with the first model

```
numpy.random.seed(seed)
model = OneHiddenLayer_Model()
model.fit(scaleX, Y, validation_data=(scaleTestX, testY), epochs=250, batch_size=numBatch, verbose=0)

numpy.random.seed(seed)
model = OneHiddenLayer_Model()
history = model.fit(scaleX, Y, validation_data=(scaleTestX, testY), epochs=500, batch_size=numBatch, verbose=0)

predictY = model.predict(scaleX)
predictTestY = model.predict(scaleTestX)
```

2.2) Scheme2. one fitting with the second model

```
numpy.random.seed(seed)
model = OneHiddenLayer_Model2()
history = model.fit(scaleX, Y, validation_data=(scaleTestX, testY), epochs=500, batch_size=numBatch, verbose=0)

predictY = model.predict(scaleX)
predictTestY = model.predict(scaleTestX)
```

3). Finally, the results are plotted for each scheme, as shown below, (model loss history --> predict on scaleX --> predict on scaleTestX),

3.1) Scheme1
[image]

3.2) Scheme2 (with 500 epochs)
[image]

3.3) add one more test with Scheme2 and set epochs = 1000
[image]

From the images above, I've found that **Scheme1** is **better** than **Scheme2**, even if Scheme2 is set with more epochs.

Can anyone help to explain why Scheme1 is better? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: The optimizer has memory due to the inclusion of 'momentum'. Updates of the past influence the way the weights are updated. I think we both expect this behaviour to be consistent when using the optimizer as a global variable, but for some reason it is not. Maybe you need to specify a starting epoch in the second run of the first case to get the same (poorer) behaviour as in the second?

Comment: Also could be due to the stochastic nature of Training NNs. Does this happen on different instances and training processes? Also could be due to the fact that the Adam object is reused on the consecutive training, so on the second fit it was already initialized and had memorized its last optimal momentum (as someone already noticed).

Comment: Thanks, KeithWM and DarkCygnus! 
The global optimizer does have influence for the second training in Scheme1, like KeithWM said. 

I've tested on 8 more datasets(with epochs=750 in Scheme2), and only 1 of shows that Scheme1 is better. 

So Scheme2 is actually better than Scheme1 for most cases, though I still cannot figure out why Scheme1 sometimes outperforms the other.